# Kinds of German rounded front vowel

Tags: pronunciation

I thought there are two rounded vowels in German as in French 'oui'(u- front rounded?) and 'soeur'(o-like front rounded?). but I find three or more of them and I'm confused...

One is ø : der knödel [ˈknøːdl̩], der Brötchen.
One is oe : der Stöckelschuh /ʃtœkl̩ˌʃuː/

and the other one is y : der Schnürsenkel /ˈʃnyːɐ̯ˌsɛŋkl̩/

Are ø and oe alike? and I guess y is the only u-like front vowel in German?

Comment: German vowels come in short/long pairs, and the short and long vowels also differ in quality.

Answer (score 4):

German has four front rounded vowels.

```
long  ö [øː]: Brötchen     (as in French "peu")
short ö [œ]:  Stöckelschuh (as in French "sœur")
long  ü [yː]: Schnürsenkel (similar to French "rue", but longer)
short ü [⁠ʏ⁠]:  Hütte        (similar to French "plus", but more like "i")
```

The French *oui* has none of these but [w] instead.

Comment: The vowels [⁠ʏ⁠] and [øː] have pretty much the same quality. They are distinct because [⁠ʏ⁠] is short/[checked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checked_and_free_vowels) while [øː] is long/free, and perceived to be very different because of the spelling. This means the closest French equivalent to the vowel in *Hütte* is the vowel in *peu.*